# How to sort month name in union query

Tags: sql, sorting

I have two query. query 1 dislay table by month name. Query two display table by workingweek. I union the two table but the problem is table 1 display not in correct order for month name.

I want to display like this:

```
October    
November    
WW52


SELECT Month, InputQuantity, ShippingQuantity FROM
(
   SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, dbo.SBR.SBR_DateCreated) AS Month, 
   SUM(dbo.SBR.SBR_Quantity) AS InputQuantity, 
   SUM(dbo.SBR.SBR_ShippingQuantity) AS ShippingQuantity 
   FROM dbo.SBR WHERE DATENAME(MONTH, SBR_DateCreated) <> DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()) 
   GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, dbo.SBR.SBR_DateCreated)
UNION
   SELECT dbo.SBR.SBR_WorkingWeek AS Month, 
   SUM(dbo.SBR.SBR_Quantity) AS InputQuantity, 
   SUM(dbo.SBR.SBR_ShippingQuantity) AS ShippingQuantity
   FROM dbo.SBR
  INNER JOIN dbo.WorkingWeek 
    ON dbo.SBR.SBR_WorkingWeek=dbo.WorkingWeek.WorkingWeek
  WHERE (dbo.WorkingWeek.DateFrom < GETDATE() 
  AND dbo.WorkingWeek.DateTo > GETDATE())
  GROUP BY dbo.SBR.SBR_WorkingWeek
) AS UWAIS

And Current OUTPUT:

Month       InputQuantity   ShippingQuantity    
November         12                12    
October          12                12    
WW52             13                10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add an additional column to each of the subqueries to represent one of the dates during the month.  This can then be used for `order by`.

```
SELECT Month, InputQuantity, ShippingQuantity
FROM (SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, s.SBR_DateCreated) AS Month,
             SUM(s.SBR_Quantity) AS InputQuantity, SUM(s.SBR_ShippingQuantity) AS ShippingQuantity,
             MIN(s.SBR_DateCreated) as mindc
      FROM dbo.SBR s
      WHERE DATENAME(MONTH, SBR_DateCreated) <> DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()) 
      GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH,s.SBR_DateCreated)
      UNION ALL
      SELECT s.SBR_WorkingWeek AS Month, SUM(s.SBR_Quantity) AS InputQuantity,
             SUM(s.SBR_ShippingQuantity) AS ShippingQuantity,
             MIN(ww.<datecol>)
      FROM dbo.SBR s INNER JOIN
           dbo.WorkingWeek ww
           ON s.SBR_WorkingWeek = ww.WorkingWeek
      WHERE (ww.DateFrom < GETDATE() AND ww.DateTo > GETDATE())
      GROUP BY s.SBR_WorkingWeek
     ) UWAIS
ORDER BY mindc;
```

Unfortunately, I don't know which column to use for the second subquery.  But there is probably an appropriate date in one of the tables.

In addition:

- I changed the `union` to `union all`.  There is no reason to incur the overhead of removing duplicates.
- I added able aliases so the query is easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Put `ORDER BY SBR_DateCreated` in the first subquery.

```
SELECT Month, InputQuantity, ShippingQuantity FROM
(
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, dbo.SBR.SBR_DateCreated) AS Month, SUM(dbo.SBR.SBR_Quantity) AS InputQuantity, SUM(dbo.SBR.SBR_ShippingQuantity) AS ShippingQuantity FROM dbo.SBR WHERE DATENAME(MONTH, SBR_DateCreated) <> DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()) 
GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, dbo.SBR.SBR_DateCreated)
ORDER BY dbo.SBR.SBR_DateCreated
UNION
SELECT dbo.SBR.SBR_WorkingWeek AS Month, SUM(dbo.SBR.SBR_Quantity) AS InputQuantity, SUM(dbo.SBR.SBR_ShippingQuantity) AS ShippingQuantity
FROM dbo.SBR
INNER JOIN dbo.WorkingWeek ON dbo.SBR.SBR_WorkingWeek=dbo.WorkingWeek.WorkingWeek
WHERE (dbo.WorkingWeek.DateFrom < GETDATE() AND dbo.WorkingWeek.DateTo > GETDATE())
GROUP BY dbo.SBR.SBR_WorkingWeek

) AS UWAIS
```